# Why does Minecraft Classic show the menu when mining/placing blocks?

Tags: minecraft-classic-browser

When I play Minecraft Classic, sometimes the menu screen appears when mining/hitting/placing blocks. It starts to get annoying when you are trying to make a giant house. So my question is why does it appear, and how to remove/prevent it.

Comment: Have you checked your key mappings?

Comment: Are you playing in the browser? If your (invisible) mouse is for some reason improperly "captured" by the game screen and goes outside it, the game will pause when you click because you're (accidentally) clicking away from the game.

Comment: No. My cursor is still in the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a late answer, but it's because the client is somehow losing focus when clicking. This is mostly because of Java changing something in mouse handling, and the older LWJGL not expecting a change.

You can downgrade to java6 to play it without this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to everyone. It happens to me too, and I think its because of keybinds. I think Classic doesnt have a grasp on which key is which, and it is a good thing that Notch udpated MC to prevent this. Do you really wanna play on classic? Why not a beta version if you wanna play old-school?

Comment: Probably because there isn't a newer version available to play free through a browser.